# "Scientific research" in Portuguese

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras, tradução-inglês, diferenças

I am trying to translate *scientific research* into Portuguese. I have: *pesquisa científica* or *estudo científico*.

What is the difference between them?

Is one of them related to laboratory work and the other one statisctical gathering data?

I prefer Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: To second @JorgeB. when you ask about the fine differences between two terms context is all important. We could go on and on writing pages about the differences between usage of *pesquisa* and *estudo* in various contexts.

Comment: The difference is the same as in English. Estudo científico is a scientific study and scientific research is pesquisa científica. Why is that no one has pointed that out? I find these overly long answers a bit trying when the answer is actually so simple. Bear in mind, in English, there is also scientific investigation, especially in "pharma" contexts....

Answer (score 4):

Both terms apply to lab work and data gathering. In fact ***pesquisa*** and ***estudo*** correspond fairly well to ***research*** and ***study*** respectively: ***um estudo*** or ***uma pesquisa*** is a piece of research on some topic. But research in all sorts of fields in general is ***pesquisa***, not *estudo*. For instance in the following headlines you could not substitute *estudo* for *pesquisa*:

> Brasil investe mais em **pesquisa científica** do que na Copa do Mundo
>   [(Globo, 26-6-2014.)](http://extra.globo.com/noticias/educacao/vida-de-calouro/brasil-investe-mais-em-pesquisa-cientifica-do-que-na-copa-do-mundo-13033250.html)
>
> Cai o financiamento da **pesquisa científica** no Brasil
>   [(Associação dos Docente da Universidade Federal do Amazonas.)](http://adua.org.br/noticias.php?cod=45)
>
> Entre 2002 e 2008, a **pesquisa científica** no Brasil deu um salto em investimentos e publicações
>   [(Exame, 13-9-2016)](http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/6-centros-de-pesquisa-para-trabalhar-no-brasil/)

If you narrow the scientific field but are still talking of research in general ***pesquisa*** is the word you use:

> Criado em 1952, o CDTN foi a primeira instituição brasileira dedicada à **pesquisa nuclear**
>   [(Instituto Qualidade Minas.)](http://www.pmqp.org.br/iqm_pmqp/paginanoticias.asp?op=2&area=&codigo=3&idioma=1&subarea=Not%C3%ADcias&cod_info=159)
>
> Mecânica estatística é ferramenta para **pesquisa econômica e social**
>   [(Universidade de São Paulo, 1-7-2014.)](http://www5.usp.br/45613/mecanica-estatistica-tambem-e-ferramenta-para-pesquisa-economica-e-social/)
>
> Durante um século e meio de **pesquisa em imunologia**, os trilhões de micróbios que vivem sobre nosso corpo (na pele, nas mucosas) foram praticamente ignorados
>   [(Sociedade Brasileira de Imunologia, 20-9-2016.)](http://sbi.org.br/diversidade-em-imunologia-revista-ufmg/)

If anything, in the examples above, you could use the plural *estudos*—“estudos econômicos”, “estudos em imunologia”—but then the emphasis would be on a number of studies rather than research in general. But when talking about a particular piece of research, *pesquisa* and *estudo* can both be used:

> Para realizar **uma pesquisa** sobre a ação da auricupuntura (aplicações de agulhas na orelha) em processos de emagrecimento [...]   [(Folha de São Paulo, 2-8-2001)](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/equilibrio/eq0208200103.htm)
>
> Um vídeo que não carrega no telefone celular gera tanto estresse quanto um filme de terror, afirmou nesta quarta-feira o fabricante de equipamentos de telecomunicação Ericsson, após realizar **um estudo** sobre as reações biológicas sofridas pelos internautas.
>   [(Folha de São Paulo, 17-2-2016.)](http://f5.folha.uol.com.br/voceviu/2016/02/10000366-video-que-nao-carrega-no-celular-gera-mais-estresse-que-esperar-em-fila-diz-estudo.shtml)

You can even find a single piece of research referred to by the two terms:

> A Universidade de Victoria, em Melbourne, na Austrália, recrutou cerca de 70 alunos para realizar **uma pesquisa** sobre mudança de ‘orientação’ no Brasil […] **O estudo** também apontou que a atividade na cama dos que ‘mudaram de lado’ também melhorou. 
>   [(Zero Magazine, 16-3-2016.)](http://zeromagazine.com.br/?p=2700)

In this context [*pesquisa* (Aulete 2)](http://www.aulete.com.br/pesquisa) and [*investigação* (Aulete 3)](http://www.aulete.com.br/investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o) are synonyms. Both term are found in Brazil in Portugal, but *pesquisa* is the most common in Brazil whereas, as Jorge notes in his answer, *investigação* is the most common in Portugal.

Comment: Eu ainda acho que vocês estão a confundir as coisa, quando se fala de research em termos académicos é como isto: http://www.estudopratico.com.br/investigacao-cientifica/ e não o termo que se usa em jornais como estudo e pesquisa. Porque em Portugal também se usa muito estudo e pesquisa em jornais, mas nos meios académicos fala-se de investigação (research)

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu teria alguma relutância em contradizer os dois brasileiros que já se pronunciaram sobre o assunto. E se fores aos sites de universidades brasileiras encontras *pesquisa* [(exemplo)](http://www.fmb.unesp.br/#!/cep). E eu tenho na resposta vários exemplos oriundos de universidades. Agora não sei quão comum é *investigação* no Brasil neste contexto. O Aulete dá [*investigação*](http://www.aulete.com.br/investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [pesquisa](http://www.aulete.com.br/pesquisa) como sinónimos.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu convivi com muitos brasileiros na universidade em Inglaterra e esta era uma das diferenças conhecidas, que nós dizíamos *investigação* e eles, *pesquisa*.

Comment: pronto eu dou o braço a torcer :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Pelo progresso da ciência dá-se até os dois se for preciso!

Comment: Jacinto, "investigação científica" soa (aos meus ouvidos) como algo específico: "será feita uma investigação científica a fim de esclarecer qual micro-organismo está causando todos esses casos de febre".  Sim, isso seria idiomático em pt-BR.  Mas eu não diria que "faço investigação científica na USP"

Answer (score 2):

To my native ears, "estudo" e "pesquisa" sound better than "estudo/pesquisa científico/a" when the reader already knows that your study is scientific.

**"estudo científico"** and **"pesquisa científica"** are often interchangeable, but not always. "Pesquisa" tends to refer to all the physical work described in your protocol whereas "trabalho" sounds more like what you have produced in writing. Some uses, however, are idiomatic:

> - "O/A presente **estudo/pesquisa** tem por objetivo provar que..."
> - "Realizamos um **estudo duplo-cego** com o objetivo..." (You wouldn't say "pesquisa duplo-cega")
> - "Nossa **linha de pesquisa** segue os cirtérios estabelecidos..." (not "nossa linha de estudo")
> - "Aguardamos o resultado do **estudo multicêntrico**..." (not "pesquisa multicêntrica")
> - "Vamos apresentar os resultados de nosso **trabalho/estudo/pesquisa** no Congresso Mundial de..."
> - "Fizemos um **estudo randomizado** sobre..." (not "pesquisa randomizada")
> - "Eu faço **pesquisa (científica)** (not "trabalho" or "estudo") na Universidade de São Paulo.  Atualmente estamos terminando um **trabalho** sobre enzimas presentes no vírus K26."

If the context is not clear, you might have to add "scientific": "Eu faço pesquisa científica na USP"

Comment: Ótima resposta (+1), mas *pesquisa multicêntrica* também é usado, não?

Comment: @eightShirt   Não seria errado, mas "estudo multicêntrico" é idiomático.  É como "café com leite"; você pode dizer "leite com café" se quiser, e será entendido.

Comment: Encontramos 'pesquisa multicêntrica' em vários resultados no google, provavelmente por alguns adotarem Estudo e outros adotarem Pesquisa, até Projeto multicêntrico é encontrado. Porém a grande maioria adota Estudo.

Comment: @AndréLyra    O local para fazer essa procura é no Google Scholar.  Compare: [**13.200**](https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=pt-BR&q=%22estudo+multic%C3%AAntrico%22&btnG=&lr=lang_pt) resultados para "estudo multicêntrico" versus [**911**](https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?q=%22pesquisa+multic%C3%AAntrica%22&btnG=&hl=pt-BR&lr=lang_pt&as_sdt=0%2C5) resultados para "pesquisa multicêntrica"  sendo que sites portugueses estão incluídos.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is used in Brazil but in Portugal we most use "investigação científica":

> O que fazes na Universidade? Faço investigação, sou
>   investigadora.

Comment: É compreensível, mas não é tão usual. Ao menos com base na minha experiência é mais fácil falarem *pesquisa* em vez de *investigação*.

Comment: No Brasil tenderíamos a achar que a moça é da polícia...

Comment: @LuísHenrique  Isso mesmo.

Comment: @LuísHenrique aqui também, mas sem o contexto da universidade.

Comment: @Centaurus vê o meu último comentário.

Comment: Existe até faculdade para ser Oficial da Polícia Militar em São Paulo.

Comment: Note-se que em Portugal um polícia não faz investigação, apesar de investigar. Mas sim, eu também acho que "um investigador" (sem mais contexto) é mais um polícia que um cientista.

Answer (score 0):

(in Brazilian Portuguese)

Generally, if you can count it, you may use either "estudo" or "pesquisa".

> Ela publicou um estudo sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia*
> no ano passado.
>
> Ela publicou dois estudos sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria
> angustifolia* no ano passado.
>
> Ela publicou duas pesquisas sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria
> angustifolia* no ano passado.

If it is uncountable, you can only use "pesquisa":

> Nossa universidade tem priorizado o ensino sobre a pesquisa, e os resultados não têm sido bons.
>
> O novo governo está cortando a verba para a pesquisa em física teórica.

Now, both words have (several) other meanings, depending on context:

Estudo: apprenticeship, knowledge, learning, etude:

> O estudo do Cálculo Integral requer um sólido conhecimento de funções
> de primeiro e segundo grau.
>
> João é um homem de muito estudo.
>
> O estudo da língua búlgara demanda muito tempo e dedicação.
>
> Maricota assassinava um estudo de Chopin em um piano desafinado.

Pesquisa: survey, poll, search:

> Uma pesquisa entre jovens no Rio de Janeiro mostrou que a maioria
> deles nunca jogou Age of Empires.
>
> A última pesquisa da Datafolha mostra o Lula na frente em todos os
> cenários.
>
> Fiz uma pesquisa no Google, mas não consegui nenhum resultado para
> "matemática canhota".

Both also have several synonyms, such as ensaio, publicação, trabalho:

> Ela publicou dois ensaios sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia* no ano passado.
>
> Ela publicou dois trabalhos sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia* no ano passado.
>
> As publicações dela sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia* representam o estado da arte no assunto.

The anglicism *paper* is also widely used:

> Ela publicou dois *papers* sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia* no ano passado.

There are situations in which one of the terms cannot be used for idiomatic reasons, such as the already mentioned "estudo duplo-cego", or "pesquisa bibliográfica".

Now, the suggested "investigação", which seems to be the preferred word in EP, can only be used as a synonym of "pesquisa" in certain contexts in BP (and never as a synonym of "estudo", I suppose). Generally speaking, it is used to designate the research activity that results in a "estudo":

> A investigação dela sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia* rendeu duas publicações e uma bolsa do CNPq.

But not

> *O novo governo está cortando a verba para a investigação em física teórica.

Nor

> *Ela publicou duas investigações sobre a reprodução da *Araucaria angustifolia* no ano passado.

(We would understand those sentences, but we would not deem them correct.)

Comment: Esta resposta abrange muitos temas. Deverias ter focalizado em responder específicamente á pergunta.