# Qual a melhor expressão, "pesquisa", "estudo" ou "trabalho acadêmico"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Seguidamente leio textos técnicos e acadêmicos com qualquer destas expressões e sem distinção ao emprego, muitas vezes escritas no mesmo texto e tratadas como sinônimos. Isso me causa um certo desconforto, talvez por ignorância minha, mas enfim. Tratando-se de textos produzidos pela academia, gostaria de saber em que casos devo, ou não, aplicar/empregar as expressões:

> - Pesquisa acadêmica
> - Estudo acadêmico
> - Trabalho acadêmico

Comment: Pode adicionar alguns exemplos? Dependendo da situação, podem ser sinônimos mesmo.

Comment: @Ramon A tua proposta de edição foi automaticamente anulada quando eu me acabei a minha primeiro. Eu ainda a conseguir ver, e creio que tinhas alterado algumas coisas que eu não alterei. Volta a editar se achares que vale pena (eu faço sempre edições minimalistas).

Comment: @Jacinto Agradeço a consideração, mas acho que a sua edição alcançou exatamente o que a minha buscava. A pergunta está bem mais clara agora.

Comment: Embora a pergunta não seja a mesma, encontrarás aqui http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/scientific-research-in-portuguese/3835#3835  várias respostas para a tua pergunta.

Comment: Jean, na minha primeira leitura pensei que a pergunta era acerca *pesuisa/estudo/trabalho* para referir o próprio texto (e.g. *este **trabalho** está organizado do seguinte modo: na secção 1 explica-se a  metodologia; na secção 2*...); mas lendo de novo, já não sei se não te referes à própria pesquisa por detrás do texto (e.g. *nesta **pesquisa** inquiriram-se 500 pessoas em três cidades*...). É importante esclareceres isto, talvez com exemplos reais, como sugere o Ramon. Caso contrário a pergunta fica demasiado vaga e abrangente.

Comment: Assim que possível atenderei as sugestões...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podem ser sinônimos, mas cada uma remete a situações diferentes:

- **Pesquisa acadêmica** - Soa mais formal, remete a idéia de um processo mais complexo, envolvendo diversos grupos ou pessoas.
- **Estudo acadêmico** - Menos formal. Idem ao caso anterior, mas sem tanta importância atribuída. Dá a impressão que uma única pessoa está envolvida.
- **Trabalho acadêmico** - Menos formal que as anteriores, dá a impressão de que alguns alunos/estudantes estão fazendo um simples trabalho.